# How can I create a HashiCorp Vault policy that prevents users from destroying secret versions?

Tags: security, rbac, hashicorp-vault

I have a policy that is given to new users who need the ability to create new secrets and new secret versions but they should not have the ability to delete secrets or secret versions. The snippet below prevents users from deleting a secret; however, they are still able to destroy every single secret version.

How can I prevent them from destroying a secret version using a policy?

```
# This section grants all access on "secrets/*". Further restrictions can be
# applied to this broad policy, as shown below.
path "secrets/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "list"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HashiCorp Vault API docs to figure this out: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/kv/kv-v2.html
https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/master/website/source/docs/concepts/policies.html.md

```
# This section grants all access on "secrets/*". Further restrictions can be
# applied to this broad policy, as shown below.
path "secrets/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "list"]
}

# This section explicitly denies the ability to destroy secret versions.
path "secrets/destroy/*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
path "secrets/delete/*" {
  capabilities = ["deny"]
}
```